# R how to label non-sequential x-axis ticks

Tags: r, plot, time-series, axis-labels

I'm following up a response by @Gavin Simpson to an earlier question about x-axis tick labeling with a question about non-sequenced tick labels.  Here is his response example to set up the problem:

```
set.seed(53)
f <- rnorm(700, 2)
dates <- seq(as.Date("04/01/2012", format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
             by = "days", length = length(f))
head(f)
op <- par(mar = c(7,4,4,2) + 0.1) ## more space for the labels
plot(dates, f, xaxt = "n", ann = FALSE)
labDates <- seq(as.Date("01/01/2012", format = "%d/%m/%Y"), tail(dates, 1),
                by = "months")
axis.Date(side = 1, dates, at = labDates, format = "%b %y", las = 2)
title(ylab = "f") ## draw the axis labels
title(xlab = "dates", line = 5) ## push this one down a bit in larger margin
par(op) ## reset margin
```

However, rather than a sequenced set of x-axis tick labels beginning at "Jan 12" and ending "Dec 13" I would like to only label several dates that are non-sequential and of a different length than f, such as March 3, 2012, April 27, 2012, October 20, 2012, and May 8, 2013, while the remainder of the plot persists.  So I set up a vector of dates to call but get tripped up after that:

```
set.seed(53)
f <- rnorm(700, 2)   # the count doesn't matter
MyDates<-c("03/03/12", "04/27/13","10/20/12", "05/08/13")   # non-sequential char string of dates not equal to f
plot(MyDates, f, xaxt = "n", ann = FALSE)
axis.Date(1, MyDates, at=c(1,length(MyDates), ??????))   #not complete and not right
```

So my question is how do I label a  set of non-sequential x-axis tick marks of a different length than the data?

I would also like to add vertical lines at the dates I choose, which I am aware may be done with `abline()`, but have yet to get there since I'm laboring over this `axis.Date` issue.

Comment: In response to the title, `las = 1` will make the y-axis labels horizontal.

Comment: Title has been edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert your selected dates from `character` to `Date` (using the right format string):

```
MyDates <- as.Date(MyDates, format = "%m/%d/%y")
# [1] "2012-03-03" "2013-04-27" "2012-10-20" "2013-05-08"

class(MyDates)
# [1] "Date"
```

Then you can add your axis with ticks at those points only:

```
axis.Date(side = 1, at = MyDates, format = "%b %y", las = 2)
```

That short axis looks ugly? Add the first and last date:

```
axis.Date(side = 1, at = c(min(dates), MyDates, max(dates)), format = "%b %y", las = 2)
```

Want to stretch the axis but not have the first/last labels? Don't print them:

```
axis.Date(side = 1, at = c(min(dates), MyDates, max(dates)), 
    labels = c("", format(MyDates, "%b %y"), ""), las = 2)
```

Or instead, draw a long axis first without labels:

```
axis.Date(side = 1, at = c(min(dates), max(dates)), labels=FALSE)
axis.Date(side = 1, at = MyDates, format = "%b %y", las = 2)
```

Vertical lines:

```
abline(v=MyDates)
abline(v=MyDates, lty="dashed", col="red")
# etc.
```

Comment: I appreciate the options but could you please help me with the issue of unequal lengths of `f` and `MyDates` in `plot(MyDates, f, xaxt = "n", ann = FALSE)`?

Comment: Huh? In your question you correctly plotted vectors of equal length (`dates` and `f`), and asked how to put tick marks at a shorter x-vector `MyDates`, which I answered. What are you trying to do in the comment now?

Comment: Well, when I put the code together as such,`set.seed(53);
f <- rnorm(700, 2);
MyDates<-c("03/03/12", "04/27/13","10/20/12", "05/08/13");
MyDates <- as.Date(MyDates, format = "%m/%d/%y");
class(MyDates);
plot(MyDates,f, xaxt = "n", ann = FALSE);
`, I get an error that 'x' (`MyDates`) and 'y' (`f`) lengths differ.  You don't?

Comment: You don't need something like `plot(MyDates,f, xaxt = "n", ann = FALSE);`. Just get rid of that line.

Comment: When I apply your suggestions on this set of data it works, but on my real data and script it doesn't work.  I'm still searching for the bug.  My real dataset is called through a database connection which I manipulate quite a bit before this specific action, so posting the real dataset is impossible for me; hence I used the dummy set above and it appears to be too simple.  In short, my 'x's are Epochs from a data table (Rdataset$Epoch) and my 'y's are distances (Rdataset$Distance) of the same length.  I can get that to plot without issue, but when I try to replace the Epochs with (cont'd)...

Comment: ... a set of a few specific dates, I get no x-axis tick marks or labels.  Very confusing and frustrating.